# Show that spectral radius $\rho(L^{-1}EL^T)\le \epsilon$ if $A=LL^T+E$ where $\|E|| =\delta\ll 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A, E$ be symmetric. $A=LL^T+E$ where $\|E|| =\delta\ll 1$. $L$ is invertable, lower triangular

> Show that $\rho(L^{-1}EL^{-T})\le \epsilon$ if $\delta$ is small.

I tried rewirting $E=A-LL' \Rightarrow L^{-1}EL^{-T}=L^{-1}AL^{-T}-I$
Hence $$\rho (L^{-1}EL^{-T})=\rho(L^{-1}AL^{-T})-1$$.

Since $A$ is symmetric I have $Q^TAQ=D$ where $D$ has eigenvalues of $A$.

I'm not sure how to proceed.

**What is the interpretation of spectral radius?**
Let say for one method of iteration, the spectral radius is $x$ and for the other it's $x^2$ where $x<1$, does this imply that the method with spectral radius $x^2$ converges twice as fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your matrix $A$.

$\left\|ST\right\|\le\|S\|\|T\|,\,\forall S,T\implies\left\|E^k\right\|\le\|E\|^k$. By Gelfand's formula $\rho(A)=\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \left \|A^k \right \|^{\frac{1}{k}}$ for an arbitrary matrix $A$, $\rho(E)\le\delta$ and $\rho(BEC)\le\rho(B)\rho(E)\rho(C)=\rho(B)\rho(C)\delta$. The result follows.

Comment: So we haven't used the symmetry property of $A$, and also this would imply it's less than $\delta$, when question asks to show $\leq \epsilon$, I'm not sure what the connection is, I could have made a mistake in the question, or question not exact

Comment: As your $A$ does not appear in your proposition at all, I do not understand why you are concerned about it.